# Excess bandwidth usage, how do I overcome this?

Tags: web-hosting, bandwidth

I received a higher than normal monthly bill from my web hosting company. They have told me that I have exceeded my monthly minimum for bandwidth usage and advised me to reduce the file size of my web pages.

Is there any way I could determine the bandwidth I require for hosting my website?  Is there a tool that I could use to monitor the usage?  I don't know which files I should be working on.

Comment: It depends on the tools provided by your hosting company. Can you give us more information about the company? Do they provide, for example, cPanel? Or some other control panel?

Comment: Ouch. What is on your site? Is it just web pages or do you have files for download or large images or is it just a very popular site with thousands of visitors? None of my customers get anywhere near their limits and there are some pretty big/popular sites on there. A url might helps us if you want us to have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Most hosting companies provide a way to monitor bandwidth usage through their control panels. You could then look and see how much you used this month and use that as an estimate or if they don't they should at least tell you how much you used to incur an overage.

If you absolutely can't get historical bandwidth info A rule of thumb I was given when I worked at a hosting company (years ago) is average page size x highest number of pageviews in one day = daily bandwidth. That would give you a little extra to handle any spikes in traffic. (Note that I don't know how accurate this is as I've never had to use this calculation because most sites that are hosted somewhere already have real bandwidth data and most new sites don't have enough traffic to worry about overages).

Answer (score 0):

While not feasable for larger sites, you could use [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) to analyze a page and see what are your biggest files.

A bonus is that it recommends several other possibilities to further minimize your bandwidth.